# Sandbox is now live!

Tags: discussion, sandbox

## You can find the Sandbox [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3129/11811).

<sup>See our past discussions on the Sandbox [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1498/11811) and [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3104/11811).</sup>

Have a question that you want to fix up or not sure if it'll be a good fit here? Or looking to help nurture the community and help increase the quality of questions on the site? The Sandbox is now open for business!

**The Sandbox will be a community effort.** I'm going to be lurking around in it trying to comment and help questions that get posted, but we can use your help too! If you're a newer user or want to make sure your question is the best it can be, I'd encourage you to post in the Sandbox first. Likewise if you're an experienced user and have some time to help out, you can always drop in and leave a comment or two on how we can shape up our future questions.

**Have a question or comment on how the Sandbox is implemented?** I've added the [sandbox](/questions/tagged/sandbox) tag, so if you have questions on how to use the Sandbox or comments for things we can do better, please post a Meta question. Criticism is welcomed!

Comment: if a new question on the live site is off topic (regardless if it has been put on hold yet or not), is it advisable for other users to recommend the OP to put their question into the sandbox for improvement purposes?

Comment: Good question @enlighten_me! I'd say if you see a question with a growing thread of comments asking for clarification/trying to figure out how to improve the question you could definitely drop a Sandbox link. I'm not sure if we should put one on every closed question though. If you want a stronger community consensus on this one, just open a new meta question and tag [meta-tag:Sandbox]!