# Additional Pro Tempore Moderator Needed! - Accepting Nominations

Tags: discussion, moderation

As some of you may have noted, I'm no longer moderating this site because I got an [awesome new job as a Community Manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313086/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-599-catherine-kuck-aka-catija?cb=1), which requires me to step down from my moderation position here. This site's in the hands of a [great team of moderators](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) but they've asked me to find another user willing to step up to help them.

---

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, we need to appoint an additional Pro Tempore Moderator to help moderate this site.

### WE NEED YOUR HELP!

Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the new Pro Tempore Moderator for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selection. You can read more about the process here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

## The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the `---` markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

## Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active in the site's activities;
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities;
- Leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write;
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> ```
> <h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>
>
> <h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>
>
> Notes:
>
> <why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>
>
> ---
> ```
>
> <sup><sup>(this section is edited in by the nominee)</sup></sup>
>
> ```
> I accept/decline this nomination
>
> I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am 
> generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may 
> want to know about me are…
>
> etc.
> ```

---

On a personal note, it's been a great experience to be a part of this site from the outset and I hope that it can continue to flourish and grow with the help of dedicated and enthusiastic users and moderators.

Comment: Shouldn't we be looking for 2-3 new mods? You're leaving some pretty big shoes to fill.

Comment: Please tell me that you'll still moderate during your spare time, through your staff rights...

Comment: Congratulations on the "move" to CM. Differences of opinion aside, it's been a pleasure to have you as a mod. Maybe as CM you can advance other issues. (Welcome Wagon, for one.)

Comment: Is it useful to add Flair to the nomination, as Robert C's - [How to nominate](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/117/278) post demonstrates?, maybe next time ...

Comment: @apaul Let's be real, no amount of new moderators can fill Catija's shoes...

Answer (score 19):

### [Em C](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/3171/em-c)

### [Meta Profile](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3171/em-c)

Em C has been very active over the last 11 months in pretty much all areas of the site -- asking, answering, editing, flagging, commenting, reviewing, voting, meta, and judging from badges, chat.  (I'm not in this site's chat often, so I can't say more about that part.)  Em C looks like somebody who cares about helping this site flourish and has made many positive contributions toward that end.

---

**I accept this nomination.**

I'm flattered by support, and would be happy to serve IPS as a moderator!

The community really drew me in to the site when I first joined - I've been very impressed by how IPS has taken shape and weathered the various thorny issues that have come up, and would love to help out as it continues to grow. I like to think my background from growing up in a rural and conservative household to living in a large and liberal city has helped me learn how to see things from other points of view. I do try to keep this in mind when interacting with users here as they come from all walks of life. Just in the time I've been here, I've learned a lot from our users and referenced some Q&A's in my own life a few times :)

I've been fairly active on the site, taking advantage of my flags and votes and reading chat / meta regularly. As a mod, I think I would be most excited to have the ability to delete inappropriate content immediately instead of waiting for more votes or comment flags to handle it, and hopefully reduce the off-topic (and sometimes heated) back-and-forths that often ensue in the meantime.

I live on the east coast US and will probably be most active in the evenings or weekends, but can also check in sporadically throughout the day. For a little about me, I'm 26 and a software engineer. Outside of work, I like to hike, sew or knit, or just hang out with my spouse and our two cats!

Comment: I’ve always loved EmC’s attitude and answers on the site. They’re one of the few users who I could recognize by name before I joined and started contributing. I was thinking of nominating them if I didn’t do myself so I’m glad that they’ll be on this list!

Comment: Em C has been notably more active in chat than other users ;) While not to the same extent as other users, they're definitely "around" and reachable.

Comment: +1 Because Em has the best hobbies! :D (seriously though, all candidates are amazing and have my upvote ;) )

Comment: EmC is one of a handful of names I know on this site and EmC in particular is one that I have minimal-to-none memory of being involved in a "spat" with other users.  Every conflict they have ever helped diffuse (that I have observed) has ended positively and they have always held their composure.  That's the kind of attitude and patience I'd like to see in a moderator for this stack (which requires *lots* of patience).  Upvote x 100.

Comment: With _two_ cats, they can't be too bad. Cats know people better than people know cats (or people).

Comment: Congratulations on your diamond, @EmC! I am sure you'll do a great job as mod here. Good luck

Comment: Thank you all for the kind words! Our other mods and Catija have been great examples that I'll be learning a lot from :)

Answer (score 13):

### [Magisch](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/2347/magisch)

### [Meta Profile](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2347/magisch)

I'm nominating myself as a candidate for the position of moderator pro tempore.

This community has proven a unique challenge in the context of Stack Exchange. I really like the progress we've made so far and would like to help out more. Even though I actively answer less these days, I'm still very invested in the community's success and would like to see it grow.

I started here late last year and have been impressed with the progress the community has made so far. I've been a room owner in this site's chatroom, [The Awkward Silence](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/61165), for a while now and I'd like to think I've acquired some skills in de-escalation and light touch moderation from that.

I live in Germany and work as a software developer and sysadmin currently. When not at work I enjoy participating in [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org) (killing spam is strangely rewarding somehow), biking, swimming and playing video games. Typical, I suppose.

Answer (score 12):

### [Avazula](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/4550/avazula)

### [Meta profile](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4550/avazula)

I am nominating myself as a candidate for the position of moderator pro tempore.

I have been on IPS for about a year and it has been impressive to see the stack evolve. You might know me for my tendancy to offer answers exploring [non-violent communication](http://www.nonviolentcommunication.com/) and [love languages](http://www.5lovelanguages.com/) solutions.
I started as a casual answerer and rapidly got caught in the reviewing process. I really enjoy helping people. Whenever I can, I try to help new users to understand how to ask a good question, explain how an answer could be improved. I'm attentive to comment whenever I flag or VTC/VTD to make sure users have the best experience possible. I'm rather quiet on meta but I do consult it regularly to make sure I'm up-to-date with the new features. I'm particularly interested in discussions revolving around `tags` and their evolution.

You can usually find me in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61165/the-awkward-silence), where I love to practice my small-talk skills with people I got to like a lot.

I'm currently living in France but I could move soon to California for work. I'm a software engineer evolving in medical solutions (mostly surgery). I love drawing ; I'm looking forward to begin a new comic project. I'm keen on most craft activities.

Answer (score 10):

### [scohe001](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/11811/scohe001)

### [Meta profile](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11811/scohe001)

I am nominating myself as a candidate for the position of moderator pro tempore.

While I've only been an active member on IPS for 3 months compared to my 5 years on StackOverflow, in that time I've grown to love the community. It's been a lot of fun to watch how we evolve and I'd love to lend a hand with that evolution in the future.

One of my focuses in many of my answers and interactions is to try to empathize with both sides in every argument and give the benefit of the doubt. Everyone thinks they're the main character in their own story, and I think it's important to examine why they're doing what they are and consider why they think they're right in their actions.

In addition to my contributions on main, I've also been lurking in the Closet to help with comment flagging, going through review queues and I just finished helping in [setting up our new Sandbox](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3131/11811)!

---

I'm a software engineer working with commercial planes. I currently live in California and will soon be moving to Texas with my SO. I'm an avid reader, hiker and rock climber and lately in my free time I've been trying my hand at 3D modeling in Blender.

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 6):

### [Sphennings](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/3150/sphennings)

### [Meta Profile](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3150/sphennings)

I am nominating myself as a candidate for the position of moderator pro tempore.

Writing answers for this site has forced me to think critically about my interactions with others I'd like to do more to give back to this community. I have been on this site since January and have been participating in community moderation tasks for almost as long. In addition to handling what shows up in the review queues participating in the newly created sandbox and am actively flagging comments to try to reduce the amount of discussion taking place in the comments. When things become contentious I try to deescalate the situation often by trying to direct users to more appropriate channels to address their concerns.

I live in the greater Boston area and work as a QA automation engineer. When I'm not on this site I enjoy biking, hiking, Pokemon Go and developing toy programming languages.

Comment: For those not in favor of sphennings as a candidate, would you mind explaining why? I happen to thing that they'd be a rather good choice, and I'm baffled by the amount of downvotes on this nomination.

Comment: @ArwenUndómiel I'm guessing the DVs have to do with previous tensions (I haven't seen any of what I'm about to list as of late).  While sphennings usually isn't wrong when pointing out what could be better about a post, the way things are phrased/perceived tone of the text hasn't always been the most patient/inviting and has caused some head butting and tension with new(ish) users.  Again, I haven't really seen this going on lately so I'm unsure if this is really the reason - but I figure it could be a possibility.

Comment: Personally I think that the level of activity, promptness, and accuracy of sphennings current moderation tactics would make for a great mod, so maybe some extra cool down time from the reasons I listed above would make for a more approving community.

Comment: I too have seen great work from sphennings, so I'm pretty disappointed to see this reaction.

Answer (score -9):

### [apaul](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/59/apaul)

### [Meta profile](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/59/apaul)

I am nominating apaul for the mod detail. I often peek in, and read content, even though I seldom add to it anymore. Interactions I've had, and seen others have, with apaul suggest to me that they are open-minded enough about the lack of globally applicable "truths" to allow everyone the right to seek solutions that fit their situations rather than the internal set of guidelines apaul may have personally. In my view, this site must have mods that will allow others to do, say, and be, what is proper for them without judging the person or their situation with external standards that don't apply. User apaul seems to care about the people behind the user name and willing speaks up when other users are not fairly treated. User apaul has my respect, and gratitude for their efforts on the site already. Modship, if they'll accept that daunting task, will not enhance, nor detract, from that.

---

**As flattering as being nominated is, I really shouldn't be a moderator here.**

I tend to be more than a little too hot tempered to do the job as objectively as it needs to be done, and I think most of us know that. This is something that I'm taking steps to address, but I suspect that it may be a while till I have it reined in enough to be considered.

I also tend to place a much higher value on contributing content than curating content, so I'm probably better suited continuing to contribute as a regular user. I doubt I would do well writing questions and answers with the added scrutiny, and time constraints, that usually come with a diamond... And when it comes down to it, contributing content is what I'm better at.

**Thanks, but no thanks.**

Comment: You nailed it paul ;) keep the good job answering though!

Comment: I wrote a really long comment to this nomination yesterday, but couldn't get it to sound right, so I ended up not posting it. Rejection sucks, regardless of the reason and that's human nature. While I'll admit I'm one of the ones who doesn't think you're a fit for this, I REALLY value a lot of the content you've put on the site and was worried you'd take the negative votes harshly. So thank you. Thank you for being cool, and thank you for some of your insightful answers that I've used to better myself, and thank you for being a very valuable member of this community.

Comment: Your ability to recognize what is/isn't right for you and put that above the appeal of achieving a higher 'status' is admirable, and already shows you're on a path of betterment.  I love your content and I sympathize with your path of growth (because I've had to take similar steps years ago).  I'm glad you're still here to contribute after all that has been said and done, and hope someday maybe the tides will turn and you *will* be better positioned for mod status.