# Thank you Catija!

Tags: discussion, moderation

Earlier this week, [Catija](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/36)'s employment with Stack Exchange ceased, as part of a [mass layoff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393806/practical-effects-of-the-october-2023-layoff?cb=1). Prior to that, she was one of the site's original moderators, having been appointed in the initial round on [August 7, 2017](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1363/1).

Less than a year after being appointed, she [had to resign](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3170/additional-pro-tempore-moderator-needed-accepting-nominations?noredirect=1&lq=1) from her position [as a condition of accepting employment at Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340713/why-are-moderators-who-become-stack-exchange-employees-required-to-resign-as-mod), but until this Monday she continued to hold moderator rights on this site by virtue of her job title. With her employment ceasing, this marks the loss of her continuous moderator rights here since 2017.

Today, she [confirmed in the Meta Discord server](https://discord.com/channels/628507458452586497/628507458910027777/1164465215748968528) (requires access) that she will not be requesting to be reinstated as a moderator here, marking a permanent (for now) end to her having moderator rights here.

As there wasn't a proper "thanks" post for her service back when she had to relinquish her volunteer mod title, please join me now in thanking her for her service to this site as a moderator. As one of the initial team of three, she was instrumental in helping to define the site's scope and keeping early content moderated, and as a staff member, she did a great job at ensuring that this site's interests were represented in the higher tiers of community management.

Answer (score 10):

Thanks @gparyani for the post to inform us.

And Catija, thanks for your service.
Wish you the best, and keep the hyppo(s) safe :)
Godspeed!